# What is the identity for "<" relation (in Category)

Tags: category-theory

This is from exercises 3.4 from Algebra Chapter 0 by Paolo Aluffi.

The question asks can we define a category in style of reflexive and transitive relation (for example, "$\le$") using the relation "<".

I think the answer to this question is "no" since I cannot find an identity (as "<" is not reflexive).

However, I would like to know in general can I define a category reflecting the structure of "<" (since somehow I been told every structure can somehow represented in category theory). If I can, what is the identity?

Here are more details on "in style of reflexive and transitive relation (for example, "$\le$")".

Say $S$ is a set and $R$ is a relation on $S$. $R$ is reflexive and transitive. Define following category:

- The Object of the category are the elements of $S$
- The morphisms $\text{Hom}(a,b) = \{(a,b)\}$ if $aRb$ and $= \emptyset $ otherwise.

It is clear that $\le$ can be form a category in such fashion.

Nevertheless I would like to know can $<$ form a category in general (not necessary in above style).

Comment: Without seeing the book it is hard to answer, unless you clarify what you mean. Is the category related to $\leq.$ Is it (1) the category of all sets with a transitive and reflexive relation, or (2) given a particular set $X$ with a transitive and reflexive relation, $\leq,$ the category of objects the elements of $X$ and a single map between $x,y\in X$  if and only if $x\leq y?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It is the case 2. I have edit the question for clarification, hopefully it helps. Thank you!

Comment: I would say that "morally" it shouldn't be possible to represent strict inequality category-theoretically, because from a categorical viewpoint, there is no notion of equality between objects: nothing of (categorical) interest changes if, given an category $C$ with an object $X$, you expand $C$ to $C'$ by adding a new object $X'$ and arrows $f : X \to X'$ and $g : X' \to X$ such that $fg = 1_{X'}$ and $gf = 1_X$ (which determines all the other arrows from $X' \to Y$ for all objects $Y$ of $C'$).